# C# hide stacktrace when throwing exception in web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

I have a old webservice that will throw an exception under certain condition. However, currently, the exception will include the stacktrace(path, method name, etc). I created a customized exception and overwrite the StackTrace property in an attempt to hide it.

Simplified example:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public List<Object> GetISShipments(string userToken)
    {
        User user = GetUserFromToken(userToken);
        try
        {
            if (!user.CountryList.Contains("IS"))
            {
                throw new ServiceException($"Access denied for country");
            }
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return new List<Object>();
    }
```

and I tried to overwrite the exception like so

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[Serializable]
public class ServiceException : Exception
{
    public ServiceException() { }
    public ServiceException(string message) : base(message) { } 
    public ServiceException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException) { }
    public ServiceException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }

    public override string StackTrace
    {
        get { return String.Empty; }
    }
}
```

**Problem I have**:

When invoking the webservice directly in the visual studio with a browser, the exception is hidden. However, when I tried to call it using SoapUI, I am still getting the exception with stacktrace.

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcR0RJVCBUZW1wXERlc2t0b3BcTmV3RUZUU1xFRlRTXEVmdHNXZWJTZXJ2aWNlc1xDb250aW5nZW5jeVNoaXBtZW50cy5hc214?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2023 18:21:41 GMT
Content-Length: 688

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; ServiceException: Access denied for country
   at myNameSpace.MyClass.GetISShipments(String userToken) in C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\NewProject\Project\MyWebServices\App_Code\ContingencyShipments.cs:line 66
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

**Other information**

.Net Version: 4

I know that it is better to wrap the response into an response object with error message than returning the class object itself. However, this is a very old webservice that is consumed by a lot of old processes for my customer. So I am trying to find a way to achieve this without having my customer to change anything on their end.

So is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Add an exception handler and return an exception object which contains e.g. the error message.

Comment: @SebastianS. can you please elaborate? I did explain that I tried to hide the stacktrace without changing the return type so my client that consumes this webservice doesn't need change anything on their end. Feel free to post an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I have over read the fact you cannot change the response type.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error thrown it actually says the following `End of inner exception stack trace`.

The stack trace is coming from the `InnerException`, not your custom exception. So although you have overridden the StackTrace, you've only done it for the top level exception.

You can override the `.ToString()` method instead to only display information you want

```cs
[Serializable]
public class ServiceException : Exception
{
    public ServiceException() { }
    public ServiceException(string message) : base(message) { } 
    public ServiceException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException) { }
    public ServiceException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        // Return anything you need here
        return Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can a global exception middleware change this behaviour? If so I would suggest:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tore.Service.GlobalExceptionMiddleware/
Source @:
https://github.com/IVTore/Tore.Service.GlobalExceptionMiddleware

Comment: That package looks to just catch the exception and write out information to the console. For middleware that's a little odd, given there's no concept of a console. Still, it may resolve the issue depending on OPs use-case

Comment: You can assign a static async method receiving httpcontext and exception for generating response.
Delegate is
public delegate Task ExceptionResponderDelegate(
            HttpContext context, 
            Exception exception
        );
 variable is:
 public static ExceptionResponderDelegate ExceptionResponder;
 Form expected is:
public static async Task MyStaticExceptionResponder(HttpContext context, Exception exception) {
    // do it.
}

Comment: "For middleware that's a little odd, given there's no concept of a console." Thats weird. It works as a charm. Better look at the explanation and the source, each quite short.
I think it may be a handy tool for you too. Thanks indeed for your kind answer.

Comment: I am getting the error with the same inner stack trace even after overwriting ToString() that simply returns Message.

Comment: @Volkan my .net version is too old for the package I believe. I am using .Net 4.

Comment: @AngryOtter Yep, it is for .Net 6.0, that's why I asked to itsdaniel0, and did not enter it here as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could throw a SoapException instead, with null details, then the stack trace won't show up.

```
[WebMethod]
public List<Object> GetISShipments(string userToken)
{
    User user = GetUserFromToken(userToken);
    if (!user.CountryList.Contains("IS"))
    {
        throw new SoapException(message: "Access denied for country", code: SoapException.ServerFaultCode, actor: Context.Request.Url.AbosoluteUri, detail: null);
    }

    return new List<Object>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually not a good way to achieve this. I ended up using what @Sebastian S. suggested and rewrote the entire webservice....

```
public class ShipmentError
{
    public string DocumentNumber;
    public string ErrorMessage;

    public ShipmentError() { }

    public ShipmentError(string documentNumber, string message)
    {
        this.DocumentNumber = documentNumber;
        this.ErrorMessage = message;
    }
}
public class ShipmentResponse
{
    public int SuccessfulDataCount { get; set; }
    public List<ShipmentError> Errors { get; set; } = new List<ShipmentEventNotificationError>();
    public WebServiceStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```